# Can I mutate a list with zip() that has multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, zip, google-colaboratory

```
hit10K = 0
miss10K = 0
set_empty10K = list(range(0, sets))
tag_empty10K = [0] * sets

# print(tag10K)
for (w, y) in zip(index_num10K, tagnum10K):
  for (x, z) in zip(set_list10K, tag_empty10K):
    if(w==x and y==z):
      hit10K = hit10K + 1
      tag_empty10K = tag10K
    else:
      miss10K = miss10K + 1
      tag_empty10K = tag10K

print(hit10K)
print(miss10K)
```

Samples of my lists:

```
index_num[0:30]=[32508, 32509, 32547, 32545, 10590, 23744, 10590, 23744, 10590, 21188, 32545, 23736, 23738, 32501, 296, 32546, 32503, 32508, 32527, 32526, 32526, 32509, 32547, 32545, 32499, 10590, 23745, 32503, 32508, 32511]

tag_num10K[0:30]=[8143, 8143, 37, 37, 20, 26, 20, 26, 20, 40, 37, 26, 26, 8143, 38, 37, 8143, 8143, 8143, 8143, 8143, 8143, 37, 37, 8143, 20, 26, 8143, 8143, 8143]

set_list10K[23740:23770]=[23740, 23741, 23742, 23743, 23744, 23745, 23746, 23747, 23748, 23749, 23750, 23751, 23752, 23753, 23754, 23755, 23756, 23757, 23758, 23759, 23760, 23761, 23762, 23763, 23764, 23765, 23766, 23767, 23768, 23769]

tag_empty10K[0:30]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I am using google colab and I am using python I am using python 3. I am building a cache simulator.
sets is 2^15.
Hit10K and miss10K are both counters.
set_list10K is a list of 0 to 2^15.The list has 2^15 elements.
tag_empty10K is a list of 2^15 zeros.The list has 2^15 elements.
index_num is the index a piece of an address that I converted to an int. The list has 10000 elements.
tag10K is a piece of an address that I also converted to an int.The list has 10000 elements

What I am trying to do is check that (index_num == set_list10K and tag10K==tagempty10K) conditions are met and thus increase the hit count otherwise it is a miss. I want to update tag_empty10K whether it is a hit or a miss in the cache simulator. When I run this code the conditions are not met and it all goes to the else statement. What am I doing wrong? Can I mutate a list with zip() that has multiple lists? Is there another way of doing this?Any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

What I tried to limit the amount of elements of the lists to 1000. I think that the **tag_empty10K** is not getting updated. I also played around with [y] to see if that would make any difference.

```
for (w, y) in zip(index_num[0:1000], tag_num10K):
  # print(w, "  ", y)
  for (x, z) in zip(set_list10K[0:1000], tag_empty10K):
    # print(x, "  ", z)
    if(w==x and y==z):
      hit10K = hit10K + 1
      tag_empty10K[y]=tag_num10K[y]
    else:
      miss10K = miss10K + 1
      tag_empty10K[y]=tag_num10K[y]


print(tag_empty10K)
print(hit10K)
print(miss10K)
```

Comment: No where in your original code do you use any mutator method, so I'm not sure why you were expecting your list to be mutated. `tag_empty10K[y]=tag_num10K[y]` is a mutator method, but I don't think it's what you mean.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I am not knowledgeable on this subject of mutator methods. I was reading other articles and I keep coming across setters and getters. Is that what you are implying that I should use?

Comment: no, aboslutely not. You shouldn't be writing setters and getters in Python. A mutator method is any method *that mutates an object*. So, say `data = [1,2,3]` then `data.pop()`, `data.append(4)` are two examples of mutator methods. `data[1] = 99` is a mutator method, because it is essentially `type(data).__setitem__(1, 99)`. So if you want to mutate your list, you need to use some method that does that, that is all that is meant by "mutator method". Note, simple assignment, `foo = bar` **never mutates**